# Compile with mingw and then debug with visual studio  2010

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, gcc, mingw, bjam

I compile the project using bjam with following command `bjam toolset=gcc` (using gcc-mingw-4.5.2)
I want to debug the project in visual studio 2010.How can it be done?

Note:Using bjam is requirment of my system.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible: the debug information and format generated by GCC cannot be used with the Microsoft toolchain and vice versa.

Comment: Downvoter: please explain. If my answer is not correct, please say so, if it is not to your liking, `Don't Kill The Messenger`...